# Jquery - Go to top button not showing at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the jquery code i am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ( $('body').height() <= ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 100 ) ) {
            $(".goto-top-enc").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $(".goto-top-enc").hide();
        }
    });

    $(".goto-top-enc").on('click', function () {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 400);
    });
});
```

and the html code is

```
<div class="goto-top-enc text-center">
        <span class="arrow-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></span>

        <p>Go to top</p>
      </div>
```

I want to `div` to be shown when the page reaches near the bottom of the page. But this one shows when i start to scroll the page and not hiding. This one works previously. But now its not working. I tried to figure out the error but i couldn't. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: please provide a working jsfiddle or any online editor.

Comment: What is your `$('body').height()`? It might not be what you think it is.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ztmjx237/

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen The same code works in JSfiddle!!!

Comment: @Griffith The same code works in JSfiddle!!!

Comment: @Griffith Its the total height of the body element.

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue on js fiddle, with the full HTML you're having the problem with.

Comment: Are you creating the "Go to top" div with AJAX at all?

Comment: Try this: $(document).on("click",".goto-top-enc", function () {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 400);
    });

Comment: Maybe you have the "go to top" div covered up with another div. Try setting a higher z-index value to your div.